# Rails Controller Namespace Inheritance Missing Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, layout, parameters, controller

Using a namespaced controller and the app's Application layout isn't being loaded.

```
# controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end

# controllers/servers/base_controller.rb
module Servers
  class BaseController < ApplicationController

  def initialize
    # I noticed params are not accessible here either...
    # Only in the child controller.
  end

  end
end

# controllers/servers/test_controller.rb
module Servers
  class TestController < BaseController

    def index
    end

  end
end
```

A pretty basic setup here. Anytime I route to `/servers/:id` it loads the page with the parameter, but the application layout does not load. I have a series of a couple controllers I'd like to all inherit from this BaseController to initialize a few things. I also noticed that besides the layout issue, the BaseController doesn't have access to url parameters. The TestController does though... Can anyone explain these two issues I'm seeing?

Rails 5.1.4

ruby 2.4.1p111

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue. Don't use an `initialize` method in your class. Rails doesn't like that. Use `before_action` instead.

Comment: Just a hunch but it might be ok if you call `super` in it.

Comment: Thanks @ulferts. That's the first thing I tried. If I remember correctly that worked for the layout, but the instance variables weren't propagating down to the other controllers. But using `before_action` fixed both issues I had.